# Use jQuery to see if user is coming from a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link on my homepage, we will call it specialLink. If the user clicks that link it will direct them to the contact page. There are also others ways users can get to the contact page from the homepage.

Using jQuery, is it possible to check if a user clicked on specialLink to get to the contact page?

I can use this to see if they are coming from the homepage, I also need to know if they clicked specialLink:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var referrer =  document.referrer;
  if (referrer == 'http://domain.tld/') {
    // Make whatever you like  
  }
});
```

Comment: Put a special URL parameter in the link, and check whether `document.location.search` contains that parameter.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for your answer

Comment: @artgb, Can you add the answer here?

Answer (score -2):

Used `indexOf()` returns the position of the first occurrence of a value in a string.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Specify the expected referring URL
  var expectedReferrer = "http://domain.tld/";

  // Check if the user is coming from the specific link
  var referrer = document.referrer;
  if (referrer.indexOf(expectedReferrer) !== -1) {
    console.log("User is coming from the specific link");
    // Perform actions or show content for users coming from the specific link
  } else {
    console.log("User is not coming from the specific link");
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - "*is it possible to check if a user clicked on specialLink to get to the contact page*". If OP had two buttons on the same page redirecting to the contact page, then this code would trigger for both buttons without any indication which button was clicked